# How to use cached_property in PropertyGroups

Tags: python, properties, cache

I'm trying to use `cached_property` to help store unchanging node and socket references for my addon to access quickly. Still, I noticed that it doesn't actually cache them and may actually do away with the `cached_property` altogether. The `__dict__` results in an empty dictionary even when testing in the Python Console.

Test Code:

```
import bpy
import time
from functools import cached_property

class MyClasss(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @cached_property
    def test(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        return 3

class ShouldWork:
    def __init__(self):...
    
    @cached_property
    def test(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        return 3

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyClasss)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.fail = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyClasss)
    bpy.types.Scene.work = ShouldWork()

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.work
    del bpy.types.Scene.fail
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyClasss)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Calling the `work` one will sleep on the first call and then all calls afterward will return 3 immediately. The `fail` one always sleeps.

Any help would be excellent! Thanks!